# Using vcpkg to install RTABMap with VSCode as editor

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I want to install RTABMap with vcpkg and then use VSCode as editor to include RTABMap into my C++  project. I installed RTABMap as described on their wiki with `vcpkg install rtabmap:x64-windows` (i also tried the x86 triplet) and then wanted to use it in my project. To get started I wrote the following cmake file based on an [example](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/discussions/29362#discussion-4813188)  from their repository:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(RTABMap_Test VERSION 0.1.0)
 
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
find_package(RTABMap REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${RTABMap_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
set(LIBRARIES
    ${RTABMap_LIBRARIES}
    ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} 
)

include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(RTABMap_Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(RTABMap_Test ${LIBRARIES})
```

and the following main.cpp file:

```cpp
#include <rtabmap/core/Rtabmap.h>

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

The cmake settings in VSCode are as follows:

```json
 "cmake.configureSettings": {
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "G:/.vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
    "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET": "x64-windows"
  }
```

However, when I run `CMake: Build` from VSCode, cmake fails with the following message:

> -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
> -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
> -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
> -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.32.31332.0
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
> -- Detecting C compile features
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
> -- Detecting CXX compile features
> -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
> CMake Warning at G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/rtabmap/RTABMapConfig.cmake:78 (MESSAGE):
> Asked for "gui" module but RTABMap hasn't been built with gui support.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> G:/.vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:843 (_find_package)
> CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
>
> -- Found RTABMap: RTABMap_CORE_RELEASE-NOTFOUND;RTABMap_UTILITE_RELEASE-NOTFOUND;optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib
> -- Found Protobuf: G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/tools/protobuf/protoc.exe (found version "3.21.12.0")
> -- Looking for pthread.h
> -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
> -- Found Threads: TRUE
> -- Found TIFF: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/tiff.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/tiffd.lib (found version "4.5.0")
> -- Found HDF5: hdf5::hdf5-shared (found version "1.12.2")
> -- Found ZLIB: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found suitable version "1.2.13", minimum required is "1")
> -- Found JPEG: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/jpeg.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/jpeg.lib (found version "62")
> -- Found ZLIB: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found version "1.2.13")
> -- Found PNG: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/libpng16.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/libpng16d.lib (found version "1.6.39")
> -- Found GIF: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/gif.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/gif.lib (found version "5.2.1")
> -- Found LibArchive: G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/archive.lib (found version "3.6.2")
> -- Found OpenCV: G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows (found version "4.7.0")
> -- Configuring done
> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
> Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
> RTABMap_CORE_RELEASE
> linked by target "RTABMap_Test" in directory G:/FKIE/rtabmap_test
> RTABMap_UTILITE_RELEASE
> linked by target "RTABMap_Test" in directory G:/FKIE/rtabmap_test
>
> -- Generating done
> CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

On the other hand, when I run `cmake . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=G:/.vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` I get this error:

> -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
> CMake Warning at G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/rtabmap/RTABMapConfig.cmake:78 (MESSAGE):
> Asked for "gui" module but RTABMap hasn't been built with gui support.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> G:/.vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:843 (_find_package)
> CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
>
> -- Found ZLIB: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found suitable version "1.2.13", minimum required is "1")
> -- Found ZLIB: optimized;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;G:/.vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found version "1.2.13")
> -- Configuring done
> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
> Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
> RTABMap_CORE_RELEASE
> linked by target "RTABMap_Test" in directory G:/FKIE/rtabmap_test
> RTABMap_UTILITE_RELEASE
> linked by target "RTABMap_Test" in directory G:/FKIE/rtabmap_test
>
> -- Generating done
> CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

The two missing variables are set in the `RTABMapConfig.cmake.in` located at the root directory of the RTABMap repository and used by the `CMakeLists.txt`, so I assume that I don't have to set them manually, meaning -- as far as I can tell -- when vcpkg installs RTABMap it doesn't properly configure RTABMap.

What to do?

Comment: ***The two missing variables are set in the RTABMapConfig.cmake.in located at the root directory of the RTABMap repository and used by the CMakeLists.txt, so I assume that I don't have to set them manually*** No when you configure and generate the project the `RTABMapConfig.cmake.in` file should generate a `RTABMapConfig.cmake` file in the build folder using [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)

Comment: But that's exactly what happens in the CMakeLists.txt from RTABMap. So I don't exactly follow you.

Comment: You said that you found the two missing variables in the `RTABMapConfig.cmake.in` when CMake generated the `RTABMap` project it should have filled the variables in the `RTABMapConfig.cmake` file that was generated. And when you use find_package() in your CMakeLists.txt these should be used when find_package reads this file. Is there a `RTABMapConfig.cmake` file?

Comment: The authors of that project don't know how to write a proper `.cmake.in` file that generates the final `ProjectConfig.cmake` file, see my "answer" (more of a hint) for more details. Note that `.cmake.in` is only used for the creation of the final `Config.cmake` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to write this as an answer due to character limitation. It's however more of a hint on what to look at rather then how to fix it.

Let's take a look at how `RTABMapConfig.cmake` is generated via the precursor file [`RTABMapConfig.cmake.in`](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/master/RTABMapConfig.cmake.in):

*Lines 18-21:*

```
find_library(RTABMap_CORE_RELEASE NAMES rtabmap_core NO_DEFAULT_PATH HINTS @CONF_LIB_DIR@)
find_library(RTABMap_CORE_DEBUG NAMES rtabmap_cored NO_DEFAULT_PATH HINTS @CONF_LIB_DIR@)

IF(RTABMap_CORE_DEBUG AND RTABMap_CORE_RELEASE)
#...
```

Not ideal for a `.cmake.in` but I'm not going to judge that. All that I'm going to say is that parts of the code rely on certain variables being set. The same variables that were `"NOT FOUND"` in your generation i.e. this line in the generation step:

```
-- [...] RTABMap_CORE_RELEASE-NOTFOUND [...]
```

If you would traverse the `.cmake.in` file down you would notice the same for the other `"NOT FOUND"` variable.

Later on we have:

*Line 47:*

```
set(RTABMap_LIBRARIES ${RTABMap_CORE} ${RTABMap_UTILITE})
```

Which is (as you probably know by now) **empty**.

### Conclusion and possible solutions:

---

The `RTABMapConfig.cmake` can't find the proper libraries (if they exist) this can be caused either by the fact that during the `vcpkg install` phase something went wrong and the libraries weren't built **OR** the `RTABMapConfig.cmake` was poorly generated and needs to be fixed (the paths to the `core` and `utilite` libraries specifically)

1. Check if something like `rtabmap_core.lib` exists and if not - compilation failed and you need to reinstall `rtabmap`
2. If ad1) isn't the case then open up the `RTABMapConfig.cmake` and look at the paths to these libraries - fix them if needed.

EDIT: If I were you I would open up an issue on `vcpkg`'s github.